# Neo4j - Return with LIMIT by amount and ORDER by date

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Background**:

- I have a queue with John and Peter who both want to buy 450 Apples (quantity = r.Amount)

  (The queue position is given by r.Created (Earlier Date = Earlier/Lower queue position)
- I have Bob and Linda who both want to sell Apples (They both own/have r.Amount)

  (Both have 1000 Apples)

  *Test Console here:*

  http://console.neo4j.org/?id=6xghxm

**Scenarios:**

- 1st scenario: 400 Apples are sold (No matter who sells it)
- 2nd scenario: 1100 Apples are sold (No matter who sells it)

**Need:**

- Only 1 cypher query for both scenarios with the only changing
  variable 400 or 1100
- 1st scenario need: Only John is returned as he can buy all 400 apples and because he has 1st queue position
- 2nd
  scenario need: Both (John and Peter) are returned, because both are
  needed to buy 1100 Apples or parts of it

I have something in mind like this, but not limiting it by 1, instead limiting it by 400 or 1100 in combination with SUM(r.Amount) of all r.announces, but I think thats not possible in this way:

```
MATCH (Pe:Person)-[a:announces]-(Pr:Product) 
RETURN Pe.name, a.Amount 
ORDER BY a.Created ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If John and Peter want to buy only 450 apples each, how could 1100 apples get sold? Also, if Bob and Linda both have 1000 apples to sell, what prevents 900 apples from being sold -- under what scenario would only 400 be sold?

Comment: The changable variable for the Cypher query is the to be sold amount of Apples. It can be 450, 1100 or like you said 900 (as a 3rd scenario) ... The need of the question is to return the needed number of buyers, also if only a part/fraction of the Apples can be bought by all potential buyers.

Comment: So, in your question, "x Apples are sold" should really be "x Apples are offered for sale"? Also, in your test console, Bob and Linda have `buys` relationships to Apples -- shouldn't they have `sells` relationships?

Comment: I updated the Test Console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rumqwm and deleted Bob and Linda as it might brings confusion ... To answer your question: Yes, x Apples are sold (No matter who sells it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [new console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/t1xagh) that demonstrates my answer (it restores the Bob and Linda nodes, but they have a `sells` relationship to the Apple node). It also adds a `priority` property to the `Person` nodes for the buyers, in order to represent the queue order.

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[s:sells]-(pr:Product {name: 'Apples'})
WITH pr, SUM(s.Amount) AS nAvailable
MATCH (p:Person)-[a:announces]->(pr)
WITH nAvailable, {p: p, amt: a.Amount} AS pa
ORDER BY pa.p.priority
RETURN
  REDUCE(s = {unsold: nAvailable, res: []}, x IN COLLECT(pa) |
    CASE
      WHEN s.unsold = 0 THEN s
      WHEN x.amt <= s.unsold THEN {unsold: s.unsold-x.amt, res: s.res + {p: x.p, amt: x.amt}}
      ELSE {unsold: 0, res: s.res + {p: x.p, amt: s.unsold}}
    END
  ) AS result;
```

It calculates the number of apples available for sale, and then goes through the buyer queue - collecting info on the buyers that are able to buy any apples. The result is an object that has the `unsold` number for apples, and a `res` collection of info on the successful buyers.

Here is the example's result:

```
{unsold:1100, res:[
  {"p":{"_id":3,"_labels":["Person"],"name":"John","priority":10},"amt":450},
  {"p":{"_id":4,"_labels":["Person"],"name":"Peter","priority":20},"amt":450}
]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, it answers more than the initial question … It needs to settle a bit, finally it helps a lot understanding whats possible with Cypher and Neo4j.